# Add a text description to ical and outlook meeting invite urls

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, calendar, outlook

Looking to populate the description sections of an ical and outlook meeting invite button in an email via ampscript.

Example, for ical, we want the `description/desc ="text"` to populate when subscribers click the ical cta button:

```
set @1URL = Concat("https://www.link.com/ical?owner=", EmailAddress, "&subject=", EventDescription, "&dtStart=", @eventDate, "&dtEnd=", @eventEndDate, "&id=", EventID, "DESC=TEXT")
```

the google version set up works fine. need to mimic the same for ical and outlook (google uses `&details=` in the url string):

```
set @googleURL = Concat("https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&dates=", @eventDateG, "/", @eventEndDateG, "&text=", EventDescription, "&details=insert text here")
```

What needs to be done to get this to pull in description of the event?

Comment: I've detailed a full "calendar invite" solution via cloudpage here, maybe it helps? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/368414/how-to-retrieve-the-triggered-record-information-in-cloudpage-marketing-cloud/368456#368456

Answer (score 1):

I believe with ical this is not possible. However, you can achieve something that is similar to the usage that you would like.
You could set up a CloudPage where you can execute a javascript library like the following one;

- https://github.com/nwcell/ics.js

Within your email, you could provide params to your CloudPage, and in your CloudPage you could retrieve this information and use it in the javascript library to generate ical file.

Hopefully this is helpful!