# Passing subscriber data from Email to Cloudpage in Different BU

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, redirect, parameters

I currently try to do the following:
If a subcriber hits a button in the email i want to pass- the subsciber information from Email into a CLoudpage which is in a DIFFERENT BU.

CloudPageURL function is not working as i can not use the ID of a cloudpage which is in a different BU.

I tried the following:

`<a href= Redirectto('http: / /mc.xxxx.xx&SubcriberKey=',@SubscriberKey,FirstName=',@FirstName) </a>`

Unfortunately it is not working. When i test with a cloudpage in same BU and using CloudpageURL function it is working fine. DO you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use the [Concat function](https://ampscript.com/concat-function/) to concatenate the URL. Also the first parameter in your URL needs to be a question mark.

`set @URL = Concat('http: / /mc.xxxx.xx?SubcriberKey=',@SubscriberKey,'&FirstName=',@FirstName)`

Then on the other CloudPage in the other BU you'll need to use `RequestParameter` function to retrieve those values from the URL.

Comment: Done, its working.thank you!

Comment: @WernerHolm You're welcome

Comment: Adding to the answer - CloudPageURL encrypts. good practice to do the same:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/366806/aes-encryption-in-ampscript/366811#366811